# polling multiple API endpoints in one stream with rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, polling

i'm currently trying to poll multiple endpoints (which are different)
the problem is i want to keep polling only the endpoints which didn't return the status i need in an aggregated manner so the flow is basically :

build the requests -> merge them to one stream -> poll for response -> check is status matches :

1. if doesn't wait and redo the flow
2. if does take the observer out of the stream

this is what i have written and it feels like i'm missing something

```
Observable.merge(buildRequests())
.repeatWhen(obs -> obs.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
.takeUntil(response -> CheckShouldRepeat(response)).subscribe(whatever());
```

thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> buildRequests())
.repeatWhen(o -> CheckShouldRepeat(v -> Observable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
```

This can help.